# Improving Jest testMatch pattern matcher

Tags: javascript, jestjs, glob

I am using Jest and using this 'testMatch' pattern to match my test files inside jest.config.js:

`testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec).[j|t]s?(x)']`

But it is incorrectly picking up some files that end in `spec.js`. I would like it to only match `.spec.js` but anything I try results in no files being found.

This regular expression seems to do what I want `/.*\.spec\.[j|t]sx?/` but I think these pattern matchers work slightly differently

What do I have to change to make it only pick up `[something].spec.js` files (or jsx/ts/tsx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, these patterns aren't actually regex. If you're looking for a keyword to start your search, they're a form of "glob patterns." Also I might be mistaken but I'm pretty sure you want either `[jt]` or `(j|t)`, not `[j|t]`, may not matter though.

That being said, it sounds like you prefer regex syntax to glob syntax. I can't say I blame you! Instead of trying to figure out the glob that produces the same behavior as the regex you're after, you may want to look at the `--testRegex` option instead (which is also the property name for your `jest.config.js` file).

take a look here: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring
As a bonus, for reasons that make no sense, `testMatch` can only take an array of patterns, but `testRegex` can take either a string (if you have just one pattern to match) or an array